# Convert Text with newlines to a List<String>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, string

I need a way to take a list of numbers in string form to a List object.

Here is an example:

```
string ids = "10\r\n11\r\n12\r\n13\r\n14\r\n15\r\n16\r\n17\r\n18\r\n19"; 
List<String> idList = new List<String>();

idList.SomeCoolMethodToParseTheText(ids);  <------+
                                                  |
foreach (string id in idList)                     | 
{                                                 |
   // Do stuff with each id.                      |
}                                                 |
                                                  |
// This is the Method that I need ----------------+
```

Is there something in the .net library so that I don't have to write the `SomeCoolMethodToParseTheText` myself?

Comment: SomeCoolMethodToParseTheText === Split

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
using System.Linq; 
List<string> idList = ids.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: Doesn't `new[] { "\r\n" }` make an 1 element array of strings?

Comment: @Hogan: Yes, it does. That invokes this `Split` override: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx

Comment: That worked great!  Thanks.  I will add split to my tool belt for future tasks.

Comment: @Hogan, @Gabe - I just do an `int.TryParse` in the foreach after.  That gets rid of any empty items.

Comment: @Hogan: Sorry, I completely misread your question. Please accept my apologies. Thank you @Gabe for correcting.

Comment: Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using `ids.split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)`

thus

```
foreach(string id in ids.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string ids = "10\r\n11\r\n12\r\n13\r\n14\r\n15\r\n16\r\n17\r\n18\r\n19";      
        List<String> idList = Regex.Split(ids, "\r\n").ToList();

        foreach (String id in idList)
        {
            //Do you stuff here  
        }
```